# Javascript: using foreach on multiple arrays at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, foreach, nodelist

I have 2 `arrays` or more likely `NodeLists`,

```
const mainSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mainSlides')
const thumbSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbSlides')
```

Currently i am iterating over them like this:

```
mainSlides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.backgroundColor = `red`
})

thumbSlides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.backgroundColor = `red`
})
```

Since they both set the same property ie; `background-color:red;`, is there a shorthand way to loop through both nodelists at once?

```js
const mainSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mainSlides')
const thumbSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbSlides')

mainSlides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.backgroundColor = `red`
})

thumbSlides.forEach(slide => {
  //  slide.style.backgroundColor = `red`
})
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="mainSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="mainSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="mainSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="mainSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
</div>

 <div class="holder">  
  <div class="thumbSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="thumbSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="thumbSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
  <div class="thumbSlides"> some mainSlides </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you give both `.mainSlides` and `.thumbSlides` an additional class such as `.slides`, then you can select all `slides` and perform your loop on that one NodeList. Otherwise, if your NodeLists contain the same amount of elements, then you can iterate one and use the index (second argument of forEach callback) to target the other node list's elements

Comment: This code work fine ! I added your code to code snippet and works nice. I give you possible fix in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select both `mainSlides` and `thumbSlides` like so:

```js
const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mainSlides, .thumbSlides');
```

Or, if you don't want to select them together (e.g. if you want to use them further separately) but just want to use them together for this specific action:

```js
const allSlides = [...mainSlides, ...thumbSlides];
allSlides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can select both in one selector:

```
const mainAndThumbSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mainSlides,.thumbSlides')
```